# Rails Select calculated values from associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I need to calculate the total sales of top 10 variants and return a hash of {variant_id, total_sales}. but total sales is a calculated attribute.

My models, 
order.rb

```
has_many :line_items
```

line_item.rb

```
has_one :variant
```

variant.rb

```
belongs_to :root_variant # ( a self_join assosciation )
```

MY query is as follow but I can't get it to return the calculated sales as it's not part of a model

```
Spree::Variant.joins(line_items: :order).where(spree_orders: {completed_at: params[:start_date]..params[:end_date]})
                                        .select('spree_variants.*, SUM(spree_line_items.quantity) as sales')
                                        .group("spree_variants.root_variant_id, spree_variants.id")
                                        .order('sales DESC').limit(10)
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Postrgresql @jarlh, I meant to write sql not mysql

Comment: @sawa how can I return 'SUM(spree_line_items.quantity) as sales' with my query

Comment: It should be returned as part of the model instance, but because it's not an attribute it's not visible in the console output. You should however be able to call `result.first.sales` (assuming you saved the result of your query in the `result` variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be able to fetch it like:

```
res = Spree::Variant.joins(line_items: :order).where(spree_orders: {completed_at: params[:start_date]..params[:end_date]})
                                        .select('spree_variants.root_variant_id as root_variant_id, SUM(spree_line_items.quantity) as sales')
                                        .group("spree_variants.root_variant_id")
                                        .order('sales DESC').limit(10)
```

then do

```
  res.map{|m| { variant_id: m.root_variant_id, total_sales: m.sales } }
```

You suppose to get array of hashes.

Let me know if this does works for you.

Cheers